# html beginner coding: image won't show up

Tags: html

I have just started to learn about coding today. I'm learning from a video on Skillshare, which isn't probably the best but I guess it will work for the basics. I know that I am supposed to type this: `<img src="image link">` but when I do it and refresh it it doesn't show up on the webpage. If I do it on this website it works. Tips?

Thank you in advance

Comment: probably path is incorrect how did you add the src?

Comment: Hi welcome to StackOverflow! If you open the page in your browser and press the `F12` function key, a small window should pop up. This window allows you to get more information about the webpage you have loaded. If you open the `console` tab, are there any warnings that you can see?

Answer (score 0):

First advice is to clear your browser cache, then try opening the broken image in a new tab or view source and check the image link to see if you have the path to your image entered correctly. Also sometimes the extension needs to be exact on some browsers jpg or png won't work if the file is written JPG or PNG.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did as you said but it still doesn't work

Comment: @luxraayy check console for the error. Right click on the page, click 'inspect' then you should see the Console option on the menu, click on it and get back with the error you see

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could post your code on the image link but I suspect the image path is incorrect or missing. `<img src = "flower.jpg">` will look for the flower.jpg file in the same folder as where your html file is being stored. Browswer will look for different locations for the flower.jpg file for these examples : `<img src = "\images\flower.jpg">`, `<img src = "http://www.nat.com/flower.jpg">`, the former it will look for a sub-directory called images from the current directory. The final example allows you to get the image file directly from a URL if you know such a file exists.

Answer (score 0):

Hi as stated `<img src="image link">` is not working due to several reason such as incorrect path. Normally the html will look to the direct path for html stored location to find the image.

Example will be `<img src="test.png">` if file does not exist named test.png it will return broken image such as like this [image] now back to your question you have stated that

> If I do it on this website it works

this is because the website have already have a image in the server name according to your `<img src="image link">` that is why it is working inside the website. Hope this explanation answered your question good luck.